# Tweepy double scraping

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I have been using tweepy to scrape twitter for about 9 months. On Friday of last week my scraper stopped working as it did two things: 1) It started to return an empty list instead of previous tweets when tweets are present on the users profile 2) scrape old tweets when only the most recent tweets should be scraped. Has anyone been experiencing the same issues? Any suggested fixes appreciated!

```
def get_tweets(username):
    # Authorization to consumer key and consumer secret
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    # Access to user's access key and access secret
    auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
    # Calling api

    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)
    text_of_tweet = None
    tweet_id = None
 
   number_of_tweets = 1
    # Scrape the most recent tweet on the users timeline
    tweet = api.user_timeline(screen_name=username, count=number_of_tweets, include_rts=False)


    # Check if string all ascii
    for item in tweet:
        text_of_tweet = item.text
        tweet_id = item.id


    if (all(ord(c) < 128 for c in text_of_tweet)) == False:
        text_of_tweet = conv_true_ascii(text_of_tweet)

    list_of_sentences = re.split(r'(?<=[^A-Z].[.?]) +(?=[A-Z])', text_of_tweet)
    text_of_tweet = list_of_sentences[0]
    text_of_tweet = text_of_tweet.split('\n')[0]

    # Write to CSV
    # csvWriter.writerow([text_of_tweet, tweet_time, tweet_id])

    # Return tweet
    return text_of_tweet, tweet_id

def conv_true_ascii(single_tweet):
    edit_start = single_tweet.encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
    edited_tweet = edit_start + b'' * (len(single_tweet) - len(edit_start))
    edited_tweet = str(edited_tweet)
    edited_tweet = edited_tweet.replace("b'", '')
    edited_tweet = edited_tweet.replace(edited_tweet[-1], '')

    return edited_tweet
```

Comment: I have the same issue since last few days, however I noticed it only happens for particular account, I'm wondering if it doesn't happen due api request overload for big accounts. Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: @t1ms0n I haven't been able to fix it. I now store the tweet ID's in a list which I just reference before I do anything with the info.

Comment: just fyi, I have asked similar question on twitter developer forum and they told me to try using v2 API which for now works well. They added - "For very high volume and high traffic accounts, be aware that the Twitter API is highly distributed and eventually consistent. We strive to provide current information but like any large scale system, you may see unexpected behaviours at high volumes.". Good luck.